# How to add child project additional output to publish items with MSBuild?

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild

I want to create an additional file and include it in the publish items of the project reference side.

## Solution structure

```
Solution
├─ AdditionalItem.targets
├─ Main
│  ├─ Main.csproj
│  └─ bin
│      └─ Release
│          └─ netcoreapp2.2
│              ├─ Main.dll
│              ├─ Sub.dll
│              ├─ Sub.sha256     (OK: Copied in build by AdditionalItem.targets)
│              └─ publish
│                  ├─ Main.dll
│                  ├─ Sub.dll
│                  └─ Sub.sha256 (NG: I want to output this in publish)
└─ Sub
    ├─ Sub.csproj
    └─ bin
        └─ Release
            └─ netstandard2.0
                ├─ Main.dll
                ├─ Sub.dll
                └─ Sub.sha256     (OK: Created by AdditionalItem.targets)
```

## File details

### Main.csproj

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.2</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\Sub\Sub.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

### Sub.csproj

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <Import Project="..\AdditionalItem.targets" />

</Project>
```

### AdditionalItem.targets

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <GenerateFileName>$(AssemblyName).sha256</GenerateFileName>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <!-- Target for copy sub project additional output to main project output -->
  <Target Name="GenerateGetCopyToOutputDirectoryItems" BeforeTargets="GetCopyToOutputDirectoryItems">
    <Message Text="**** GenerateGetCopyToOutputDirectoryItems ****"/>

    <PropertyGroup>
      <GenerateFullPath>$([System.IO.Path]::GetFullPath('$(OutputPath)$(GenerateFileName)'))</GenerateFullPath>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
      <FileWrites Include="$(OutputPath)$(GenerateFileName)"/>

      <AllItemsFullPathWithTargetPath Include="$(GenerateFullPath)">
        <TargetPath>$(GenerateFileName)</TargetPath>
        <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      </AllItemsFullPathWithTargetPath>
    </ItemGroup>
  </Target>

  <!-- Target for create additional output -->
  <Target Name="GenerateAdditionalItems" AfterTargets="Build" Inputs="$(OutputPath)$(TargetFileName)" Outputs="$(OutputPath)$(GenerateFileName)">
    <Message Text="**** GenerateAdditionalItems ****"/>

    <GetFileHash Files="$(OutputPath)$(TargetFileName)">
      <Output TaskParameter="Items" ItemName="Hash" />
    </GetFileHash>

    <WriteLinesToFile File="$(OutputPath)$(GenerateFileName)" Lines="@(Hash->'%(FileHash)')" Overwrite="true"/>
  </Target>

</Project>
```

### What I have tried

I was able to make a copy sub project additional output to main project output in build.

But I could not copy the file to publish directory in main project publish.

#### Build output in Main\binRelease\netcoreapp2.2

```
Main.dll
Main.pdb
Sub.dll
Sub.pdb
Sub.sha256
...
```

#### Publish output in Main\binRelease\netcoreapp2.2\publish

```
Main.dll
Main.pdb
Sub.dll
Sub.pdb
...
```

I want to include `Sub.sha256` at the publish.

## Other things I tried

Target `GetCopyToOutputDirectoryItems` is also executed in publish, I added the following.
But the result did not change.

```xml
<AllPublishItemsFullPathWithTargetPath Include="$(GenerateFullPath)">
  <TargetPath>$(GenerateFileName)</TargetPath>
  <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
</AllPublishItemsFullPathWithTargetPath>
```

## Questions

- I want to add child project output to the parent project's publish.
- I do not want to write in the parent project csproj but I want to write in the targets file that the child project imports.
- I want to do the same thing as Razor class library project outputs `Project.Views.dll` in addition to `Project.dll`.

Comment: What's the special reason you can't modify the main.csproj? If for some reason you can't modify the main.csproj, what about using directory.build.props?

Comment: The reason is to create a NuGet package containing AdditionalItem.targets and reuse it in other projects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve myself in the following way.

```xml
<!-- Target for copy sub project additional output to main publish output -->
<Target Name="GenerateGetCopyToPublishDirectoryItems"
        BeforeTargets="GetCopyToPublishDirectoryItems"
        Returns="@(AllPublishItemsFullPathWithTargetPath)">
  <Message Text="**** GenerateGetCopyToPublishDirectoryItems ****"/>

  <PropertyGroup>
    <GenerateFullPath>$([System.IO.Path]::GetFullPath('$(OutputPath)$(GenerateFileName)'))</GenerateFullPath>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <Message Text="$(GenerateFullPath)"/>

  <ItemGroup>
    <AllPublishItemsFullPathWithTargetPath Include="$(GenerateFullPath)">
      <TargetPath>$(GenerateFileName)</TargetPath>
      <CopyToPublishDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToPublishDirectory>
    </AllPublishItemsFullPathWithTargetPath>
  </ItemGroup>
</Target>
```